# making stand-alone binaries in Julia?

Tags: compilation, julia, executable

Is there a way to make stand-alone binaries that contain all julia dependencies and do not require the user to have julia installed? I think it is possible to do using the Go language. It is very hard to do in other languages like Python and I wanted to know if Julia can do this or if there are plans to do it.

Comment: [Relevant thread from julia-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-dev/qdnggTuIp9s). tl;dr, it is being worked on, but I don't think anyone has committed to an exact time-frame yet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not officially supported really yet, but [there is some functionality to do it](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/9438). By "not officially supported" I mean that I don't think its being tried regularly, and isn't being checked for regressions.

I understand it is planned to make it easier in the future, but that its not a very high priority right now (can't find citation right now).